# FIMSynchronizationService SharePoint 2013 EventID 6324

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

FIMSynchronizationService SharePoint 2013 EventID 6324

Log Windows:

> BAIL: MMS(6116): sql.cpp(252): 0x80040e4d  
> BAIL: MMS(6116):
>   storeimp.cpp(234): 0x80040e4d ERR: MMS(6116): server.cpp(373): Failed
>   to connect to the database on SPS 
> BAIL: MMS(6116):
>   server.cpp(374): 0x8023043f (Service start up has failed. A connection
>   to SQL Server could not be established because of an authentication
>   failure.)  
> BAIL: MMS(6116): server.cpp(3860): 0x8023043f (Service
>   start up has failed. A connection to SQL Server could not be
>   established because of an authentication failure.)  
> BAIL:
>   MMS(6116): service.cpp(1539): 0x8023043f (Service start up has failed.
>   A connection to SQL Server could not be established because of an
>   authentication failure.) ERR: MMS(6116): service.cpp(988): Error
>   creating com objects. Error code: -2145188801. This is retry number 0.
>   
> BAIL: MMS(6116): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022  
> BAIL:
>   MMS(6116): scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022 
> BAIL:
>   MMS(6116): server.cpp(251): 0x80131022 BAIL: MMS(6116):
>   server.cpp(3860): 0x80131022 
> BAIL: MMS(6116): service.cpp(1539):
>   0x80131022 ERR: MMS(6116): service.cpp(988): Error creating com
>   objects. Error code: -2146234334. This is retry number 1.  
> BAIL:
>   MMS(6116): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022  
> BAIL: MMS(6116):
>   scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022  
> BAIL: MMS(6116):
>   server.cpp(251): 0x80131022  
> BAIL: MMS(6116): server.cpp(3860):
>   0x80131022  
> BAIL: MMS(6116): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022 ERR:
>   MMS(6116): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code:
>   -2146234334. This is retry number 2.  
> BAIL: MMS(6116): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022  
> BAIL: MMS(6116):
>   scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022  
> BAIL: MMS(6116):
>   server.cpp(251): 0x80131022  
> BAIL: MMS(6116): server.cpp(3860):
>   0x80131022  
> BAIL: MMS(6116): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022 ERR:
>   MMS(6116): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code:
>   -2146234334. This is retry number 3.  
> BAIL: MMS(6116): service.cpp(1002): 0x80131022 Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.49

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting: We know the service can't start which means something in the service or configuration is faulty.

[image]

If you were to run [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) Jump and filter for miiserver.exe, you will find the binary reads all over the file system and system registry.

We can save some time by knowing the configuration for the synchronization service is essentially in two places: In the registry (HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Service\FIMSynchronizationService\Parameters) and in the FIMSynchronizationService database.

If we look in the registry, there is no sign of a computer_id value...

[image]

If you run SQL Management Studio and look at the tables in the FIMSynchronizationService database...

[image]

If we look at the dbo.mms_server_configuration table, we find the following:

[image]

If you query the table you will find that the value in computer_id should be the name of the server running the synchronization service.

[image]

If this value "MIM" is not our computer name (and it's not), you will be be tempted to change the value to the correct computer name directly in SQL.  Don't.  Instead, either run the MIISActivate.exe which by default exists in **SharePoint 2010** - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Forefront Identity Manager\2010\Synchronization Service\Bin 
or re-run the synchronization installation and specify the same settings by specifying the existing SQL server and FIMSynchronizationService database.

Comment: How did you know it was not a permission based issue ? :) I'd like to improve my UPS troubleshooting skills. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your log states an authentication failure.

Check if the sync service is running in windows services. Ensure that it’s running using the farm account. The farm account MUST be in the local administrators group.

Also check with your dba  the following feature : extended protection
on SQL. It needs to be disable if you are using FIM.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ff487261.aspx

Of course you need to check databases permissions too.

Comment: The rights to replicate changes to the directory should be given before attempting to start the profile synchronization service? Or is it not important? Service on idea should and so it is launched?

Comment: You should stop the service, do all the appropriate changes, then restart the timer job and start again the User Profile Synchronization service.  If despite all of this you still have issues, try to run miisclient.exe located under ..\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell In the wosrt case scenario, try to rebuild the whole UPS application.

Comment: If you rebuild it, please follow step by step what is described here : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/02/18/sharepoint-20102013-user-profile-synchronization/